# Share Div as an Image/Screenshots?

Tags: jquery, html

Does anyone know of a plugin or opensource code that essentially allows you to share a DIV via social media as an image/screenshot? I know that you can save a div as an image, but I can't seem to find any library out there that would all you to share, via twitter, or `facebook` as an image.

Answer (score 0):

> Well i know for facebook

Check out this [HyperArts tutorial](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-share-button-iframe-tab-applications/) on adding a Share Button to an iFrame tab - you use the exact same code for your webpage. You will be using the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

At the end of the tutorial it explains how to modify it to allow for multiple Share buttons on one page. You just need to add a unique identifier for each one.